# "Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem" error when sending transaction using monerophp monero-integrations/monerophp transfer_split

Tags: daemon, rpc, wallet, payment-integration, php

I am using the testnet for your information, and this error keeps popping up after calling the walletRPC::transfer_split() method. I have no clue what to do. And not really sure what to do,

for what it is worth:

```
2023-11-16 22:38:56.685 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:38:56.843 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:38:57.034 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:38:57.359 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:38:57.594 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:38:57.830 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:38:58.037 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:38:58.257 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:38:58.454 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:38:58.657 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:38:58.823 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:38:59.005 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:38:59.195 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:38:59.367 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:38:59.606 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:38:59.819 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:39:00.021 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:39:00.369 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:39:00.377 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:39:00.563 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:39:00.752 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
2023-11-16 22:39:00.954 E Unable to send transaction(s) via Dandelion++ stem
```

Were the errors. I have two nodes, one wallet RPC client, and one wallet open. I am mining with a fixed difficulty of 10 to an address for a wallet that is not open at the moment. I am stumped, I have had this issue before, rarely, when using the GUI wallet, but not sure what to do now that it is giving me this error via the wallet JSON RPC API.

The server error in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`:

```
2023/11/17 09:49:42 [error] 879#879: *122 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Request have return error: transaction was rejected by daemon; 
Request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"transfer_split","params":{"destinations":[{"amount":1033357755000000,"address":"BYRxpkhZASeMd9PSZPDFxpWw9w5ETvpf4caHyXw6vZZGHB2sVyzcUH3F9AqqdYXSaTCqdiTXb8qEpcBZt3BWn4WA5DAaJXz"}],"mixin":15,"get_tx_key":true,"account_index":0,"subaddr_indices":"","payment_id":"","priority":1,"unlock_time":0,"do_not_relay":false}};  in /var/www/include/vendor/monero-integrations/monerophp/src/jsonRPCClient.php:151
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/include/vendor/monero-integrations/monerophp/src/jsonRPCClient.php(96): MoneroIntegrations\MoneroPhp\jsonRPCClient->validate()
#1 /var/www/include/vendor/monero-integrations/monerophp/src/walletRPC.php(111): MoneroIntegrations\MoneroPhp\jsonRPCClient->_run()
#2 /var/www/include/vendor/monero-integrations/monerophp/src/walletRPC.php(619): MoneroIntegrations\MoneroPhp\walletRPC->_run()
#3 /var/www/include/payment.php(191): M" while reading response header from upstream, client: ::1, server: _, request: "POST /refund.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/checkout"
```

I have `8817.295` XMR (not piconero) in my unlocked wallet balance attached to the wallet being used by the wallet-rpc client.

EDIT:

Now I am getting the error: `{snipped JSON tx info} (invalid input)` with the exact same code...